# Why would I want to load AngularJS files in any order with AngularJS Loader?

Tags: angularjs

This question has been asked before and I see most answers suggest to look at the angular seed which does this:

```
// include angular loader, which allows the files to load in any order
/*
 AngularJS v1.0.0rc1
 (c) 2010-2012 AngularJS http://angularjs.org
 License: MIT
*/
'use strict';(function ..............................................
$script([
  'lib/angular/angular.js',
  'js/app.js',
  'js/services.js'
], function() {
  // when all is done, execute bootstrap angular application
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

But I still don't understand what advantage there is with the loader. Can someone explain to me what is the difference between the above and the following code:

```
<script src='lib/angular/angular.js'></script>
<script src='js/app.js'></script>
<script src='js/services.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['mainApp']);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this simple example, it might not matter. When you have many modules which are dependent on each other however, you quickly end up with a managment nightmare. For example loading moduleB.js before moduleA.js (if moduleB relies on moduleA) would cause an error. angular loader will load moduleA.js first, even if it is defined after moduleB.js in the array.

Another benefit is that it loads files asynchronously (which would be useful if you have different areas of your application with different library requirements: the async load allows the the home page to render and start running before those libraries become available).

Comment: Can you explain how Angular loader knows to load ModuleA first if it is defined after ModuleB in the array?

Comment: Also in the async loader example I see they use another js called script.js  What's this used for?

Comment: I think I misrepresented the angular loader. Since you are adding things to angular.module(... as long as you don't run any code, it can be included any order. The loader ensures that you have the namespace to start adding in modules.

Comment: the async script loader is actually a separate deal:
https://github.com/ded/script.js
and gives you the ability to specify a batch of scripts to load in any order as quickly as possible. In the index example, all the deps will be loaded simultaneously, and the angular loader code will protect us so that regardless of which code comes back first we won't get "module undefined" errors as it is evaluated into the page.

Comment: @benschwartz , That's not really true. if you are trying to attach directives to a module that is included in a file that hasn't been loaded yet, you will run in to problems. In this case order does matter.